# How to install a file from an external directory in wix?

Tags: file, directory, wix, copy

I am trying to rewrite my msi package authored with wix to use external instead of embedded files. For this purpose, I have replaced the following `MediaTemplate` element:

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

with Media elements. I want some of my files to be embedded and others should be external. For this purpose, I have created the following two `Media` elements

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyCab.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<Media Id="2" DiskPrompt="!(loc.DskPrmptDisk1)" Layout="Files"/>
```

Following are two examples of `File` elements referencing each one of the `Media` elements:

```
<File Id="EmbeddedIniFile.ini" Name="SomeIni.ini" Source="Features\All-in-one\Files\IniFiles\SomeIni.ini" KeyPath="yes" Compressed="yes" DiskId="1"/>
<File Id="AppData.exe" Name="AppData.exe" Vital="no" Source="Features\AnotherFeature\Files\ExeFiles\AppData.exe" KeyPath="yes" Compressed="no" DiskId="2"/>
```

As you can see, the first `File` element's `Compressed` attribute is set to `yes`, while the second element's `Compressed` attribute is set to `no`. The `DiskId` attribute in the first `File` element could be omitted. Installing the embedded file works fine, however installing the uncompressed file fails with the following entries in the installation log:

```
MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: Executing op: ChangeMedia(MediaVolumeLabel=Label,MediaPrompt=Insert Disk.,,BytesPerTick=32768,CopierType=0,,,,,,IsFirstPhysicalMedia=0)
MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=AppData.exe,SourceCabKey=AppData.exe,DestName=AppData.exe,Attributes=8704,FileSize=451072,PerTick=32768,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=5.5.3.0,Language=1031,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: File: C:\Programs\MyProgramme\AppData.exe;  To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file

MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: Source for file 'AppData.exe' is uncompressed, at 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\'.

InstallFiles: File: AppData.exe, Directory: C:\Programs\MyProgramme\, Size: 451072
MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Programs\MyProgramme\AppData.exe 
MSI (s) (E8:00) [16:56:45:570]: Note: 1: 1308 2: C:\Documents and Settings\user\AppData.exe
```

Note that I have moved the installation files to the user folder `C:\Documents and Settings\user\`. The installer Falsely searches the root directory of the installation instead of the `Files` directory as specified in the `Layout` attribute of my second `Media` element. How can I force the installer to use the right child directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that I set the `Package@Compressed` attribute to `yes`. This somehow did interfere with uncompressed resources, so I removed it. Now I have organized all my resources in Media elements. Unfortunately I have not been able to mix compressed and uncompressed resources. And I have not been able to specify the `Media@Layout` attribute and still have a working installer. But externalizing **all** resources works this way.